# Webscraping Currency Data using Python 3.10 with Requests & BeautifulSoup: can't get page to update

Tags: python, post, beautifulsoup, python-requests, finance

I'm trying to extract currency exchange data from a website. The problem I have is that data from each date is retrieved by entering the date into an entry field on a website and pressing a button. The button is a oneclick element and when I can't seem to figure out a way to get the relevant date's data pulled. So far, my script continuously just pulls the data on the landing page and can't query anything.

The website: http://www.sanarate.ir/ (Dates used are Jalali, and there is no data on weekends/holidays but here are a few dates that yield data for reference: 1401/11/16, 1401/11/08, and 1401/11/01).

My code: The new page needs to be queried in step 6

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openpyxl

# Step 1 & 2
url = "http://www.sanarate.ir/"
response = requests.get(url)

with open("initial_page.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(response.text)

# Step 3
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("exchange.xlsx")
sheet = workbook["Sheet1"]

dates = [cell.value for cell in sheet["A"]][1:]

# Step 4
for date in dates:
    print("Date:", date)

    # Step 5
    data = {"MainContent_ViewCashChequeRates_txtDate": date}

    # Step 6
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)

    with open("queried_page.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(response.text)

# Step 7

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    td_elements = soup.find_all("td")

    usd_index = None
    for i, td in enumerate(td_elements):
        if td.text == "USD":
            usd_index = i
            break

    if usd_index:
        exchange_rate = td_elements[usd_index + 3].text
        print("Exchange Rate:", exchange_rate)
    else:
        print("USD exchange rate not found")
    

    # Step 8
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value == date:
            sheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value=exchange_rate)
            break

# Step 9
workbook.save("exchange.xlsx")
```

I tried viewing the post request using Chrome's devtools network tab, and in the very end of the post request's payload, there date is there. I just can't figure out how to implement that in my code especially since it appears that the rest of the payload is also changing.

Comment: I can't pull the data for a specific day because I can't figure out how to interact with a button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to focus this answer only on the issue of getting the exchange rates for a particular date. You'll have to fold the answer into the rest of the code.

The exchange rates are obtained dynamically using javascript. So you need to do this:

```
#you get the info below from the Network tab in Developer tools in your browser
#note that the date I randomly chose (2022/02/03) is in the data parameter
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Origin': 'null',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

data = {
'ctl00$MainContent$ViewCashChequeRates$txtDateEng': '2022/02/03',
    'ctl00$MainContent$ViewCashChequeRates$LinkButton1': 'Show',
}

response = requests.post('http://www.sanarate.ir/Default.aspx', headers=headers, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(' Currency, Currency Code, Bid , Offer  ,Bid  ,  Offer')
for cur in (soup.select('tbody > tr')):
    print([item.text for item in cur.select('td')])
```

Output:

```
Currency, Currency Code, Bid , Offer  ,  Bid  ,  Offer
['یورو', 'EUR', '326,055', '329,017', '302,759', '305,509']
['درهم امارات متحده عربی', 'AED', '82,823', '83,576', '76,905', '77,604']
```

etc.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it working. When I comment out the 'data = { ... ... ' and remove the data from the request, I can get the data from the current date but can't pull. Also it seems the output you received is also actually from the current date, and not 2022/02/03.

Comment: @George "When I comment out the 'data = { ... ... ' and remove the data from the request" - why would you that? Without it you get the current date information.